# Statement to display create table SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, shortcut

Is there a `stored procedure` or some SQL that I could run that would display the SQL for creating a table from an existing table?  Like `sp_helptext` to display the contents of a `function` or `stored procedure`.  Basically, is there a way to do the `Script Table As->CREATE TO` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. If you start profiler, and run [scirpt table]>[create to] in SSMS, then you'll see a series of sp_executesql being ran on sys.* tables. This means that no CREATE TABLE commands are stored anywhere in SQL server, and SSMS assemblies CREATE statements for a table from a lot of different sources.

On the other hand, if run [script view]>[create to], you'll see a simple query from sys.all_objects, sys.sql_modules, sys.system_sql_modules, where definitions are stored.